# RoutePrefix in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I use **.net framework 4.0** and **web api 1**.

I need to use attribute **RoutePrefix**, which is in **web api 2**.

Is there analog in first web api?

In Web Api 2:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/file")]
public class FileController : ApiController
{
 ...
```

My Api Controller:

```
public class FileController : ApiController
{
    private IFileManager fileManager;

    public FileController()
        : this(new LocalFileManager(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"\Album"))
    {
    }

    public FileController(IFileManager fileManager)
    {
        this.fileManager = fileManager;
    }

    // GET: api/Photo
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        var results = await fileManager.Get();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { photos = results });// (new { photos = results });
    }

    // POST: api/Photo
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Unsupported media type");// BadRequest("Unsupported media type");
        }

        try
        {
            var photos = await fileManager.Add(Request);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Message = "Photos uploaded ok", Photos = photos });// Ok(new { Message = "Photos uploaded ok", Photos = photos });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.GetBaseException().Message);// BadRequest(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        }

    }

    // DELETE: api/Photo/5
    [HttpDelete]
    [ActionName("{fileName}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delete(string fileName)
    {
        if (!this.fileManager.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);// NotFound();
        }

        var result = await this.fileManager.Delete(fileName);

        if (result.Successful)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { message = result.Message });// Ok(new { message = result.Message });
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result.Message);// BadRequest(result.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

My WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    //public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings { get; private set; }
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FileApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/file/{action}/{fileName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "File", action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My angular factory:

```
function fileManagerClient($resource, $http) {
    return $resource("api/file/:fileName",
            { fileName: "@fileName" },
            {
                'query': { method: 'GET' },
                'save': { method: 'POST', transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } },
                'remove': { method: 'DELETE', url: 'api/file/:fileName', params: { name: '@fileName' } }
            });
```

What i need to change to fix it?

Comment: Route prefix was added to web api 2 as you already know. I believe there were some third party projects that had tried originally to do the same but you would have to check the repositories. Is there no way to upgrade to web api 2

Comment: .net framework 4 not compatible with web api 2 as I know.

Comment: in webApiConfig which Route I need to add to get the PhotoController by api/photo?

Comment: the generic convention-based default route `api/{controller}` should work. You could still create one specific to photo controller  `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "PhotoApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/photo/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Photo", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In WebApiConfig which Route I need to add to get the FileController
>   by api/file?

the generic convention-based default route with `api/{controller}` should work. You could still create one specific to file controller if you want to target that controller.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

        // Convention-based routing.

        //GET api/file
        //POST api/file
        //DELETE api/file/somefilename
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FileApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/file/{fileName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "File", fileName = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The order of registering the routes in the route table is important as first matched route wins. Register more specific routes first before more general routes to avoid false matches.

Comment: error in Browser console: angular.js:12011 GET http://localhost:1300/api/photo 404 (Not Found). But if write url (by hand) like this: http://localhost:1300/api/photo/get/Album it works fine.

Comment: update your question and Show the controller. route is probably missing a default action.

Comment: change question

Comment: Order of register route is important. put file route before default route

Comment: Also noticed that you have `FileController` and not `PhotoController`. Be clear about what it is you want. your example is confusing

Comment: Thank you for explaining, it works fine now. My mistake was because in webApiConfig i use **id** as parameter, but in angular i use **fileName**. this is evident in the question.